# different cloudsearch relevance scores for equivalent matches

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I'm new to AWS CloudSearch and have set up my first domain. It only has one basic text index field.

I've tried a number of simple searches and – more often than not – I get different relevance scores across documents where it seems they should be the same. Even searching for one simple word, which matches exactly once in a number of documents, often produces different scores.

Is this supposed to happen? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Document length is one factor that will affect this. Think about it: finding your query in a 5 word document indicates a better match than finding your query in a 1000 word document.

The current version of CloudSearch [uses Solr/Lucene](http://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/03/25/amazons-cloudsearch-gets-solr-powered/), an Apache project, so you can dig into the internals to your heart's content if you'd like to learn more. Here is the [Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) which discusses the underlying scoring algorithm in Lucene.

As your app matures, you may want to look into [custom ranking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html) of your results. CloudSearch provides this capability as well as a tool for comparing the results according to different rankers. You aren't able to customize the base document relevance score but you can boost it according to different fields, etc.

Comment: Document length will probably have been one of the factors, as some entries were longer than the others. That's also why I didn't find anything about it in the CloudSearch docs – it's a consequence of the underlying tech. Thanks! :-)